# Dynamic TableHeader view Height only work on iPhone 6S size???

Tags: ios, tableheader

I met a weird problem. Now my TableHeaderView size is dynamic based on text length. Also I use constraints to arrange different components. here is how i create tableheaderview...

```
 // dynamic tableheaderview

self.postHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EPPostHeader"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil] lastObject];

[self.postHeaderView setViewWithPost:self.post];

[self.postHeaderView setNeedsLayout];
[self.postHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];

CGFloat height = [self.postHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

//update the header's frame and set it again
CGRect headerFrame = self.postHeaderView.frame;
headerFrame.size.height = height;
self.postHeaderView.frame = headerFrame;
self.postHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.postHeaderView;
```

the thing is if run on iPhone 6s, it looks great. exactly what i want. but on other iPhones ( 6s plus, 5, 4 ), the result looks incorrect. Is there anyone having this situation before? It would be a great help if someone knows how to deal with it...

[image]

Comment: problem solved...  i change all the constraints setting then it works...